# SQL Query To Obtain multiple Rows where one Row occurs more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select all records where a MerchantSequenceKey is associated with more than one ChainOID with a ChainTypeOID of 2. This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT MerchantSequenceKey
FROM hpstChainList cl
JOIN hpstChains c ON cl.ChainOID = c.ChainOID
WHERE c.ChainTypeOID = 2
GROUP BY MerchantSequenceKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns 794 records but without the ChainOID associated with each record. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to return both the ChainOID AND the MerchantSequenceKey.

Sample data that I want would look something like this:

```
ChainOID  MerchantSequenceKey
27528     128742
42862     128742
27528     128745
42862     128745
27528     128748
42862     128748
5488      132767
39248     132767
5522      133218
16033     133218
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Knowing where the columns come from would help.

Answer (score 2):

You want to group the data by merchant to count the chains, but also display the ungrouped results. I don't think you can do both at once, so you need to get
your list of wanted MerchantSequenceIDs as a subquery, and run your basic query outside it to get the data you want to display using just those merchants. Something like

```
SELECT CL.ChainOID, MerchantSequenceKey
FROM hpstChainList cl
JOIN hpstChains c ON cl.ChainOID = c.ChainOID
WHERE c.ChainTypeOID = 2
   AND MerchantSequenceKey in
(
  SELECT MerchantSequenceKey
  FROM hpstChainList cl
  JOIN hpstChains c ON cl.ChainOID = c.ChainOID
  WHERE c.ChainTypeOID = 2
  GROUP BY MerchantSequenceKey
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add ChainOID in group by

```
SELECT MerchantSequenceKey,c1.ChainOID
FROM hpstChainList cl
JOIN hpstChains c ON cl.ChainOID = c.ChainOID
WHERE c.ChainTypeOID = 2
GROUP BY MerchantSequenceKey,c1.ChainOID
HAVING COUNT(distinct c1.ChainOID) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `GROUP` with `ChainOID`

```
SELECT cl.MerchantSequenceKey, c.ChainOID
FROM hpstChainList cl
JOIN hpstChains c ON cl.ChainOID = c.ChainOID
WHERE c.ChainTypeOID = 2
GROUP BY cl.MerchantSequenceKey, c.ChainOID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need a `JOIN`.  I just don't know what table things come from.

So, this should work:

```
SELECT cl.MerchantSequenceKey
FROM hpstChainList cl
GROUP BY cl.MerchantSequenceKey
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN cl.ChainTypeOID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```